Deuteronomy 32:8-9 and Gentiles
Deut 32:8, 9

“8 When the Most High divided the nations, When he scattered the sons
of Adam, He set the boundaries of the nations by the number of the
God’s angels (b’eni yisrael). 9 For the Lord’s portion became the people
of Jacob, the allotment of His inherence is Israel”.

Depressing, isn't it for a “Gentile” reading these lines?
My question is: Who's listening to our(gentiles not dwelling in Israel)’s prayers?
The structure of the communication between the “b’eni alohim” and the Father is not described anywhere to realize if “Gentiles” have any priority whatsoever or as Jubeelium describes “Gentiles are subject to annihilation”.
Appreciate some info, not comfort!

Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour and the Help, below, as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. The term 'Father' (applied to Deity) is not revealed until the sending of the Son, so I am not, yet, clear as to what you are asking, myself.

Let me begin by correcting some facts.

"angels" is not a translation of the Hebrew which reads בְּנֵ֥י יִשְׂרָאֵֽל = bene yisra'el = "sons of Israel".

It is the Septuagint, translated from the Hebrew to Greek that has, ἀγγέλων θεοῦ = "angels of God" - quite incorrect and misleading.


Thus, all that Deut 32:8 is saying - God allocated land to the sons of Israel (ie, the nation of Israel) according to the size/population of each tribe.  It says nothing about Gentiles except that boundaries were set by God.
Of the modern versions:

"Sons of Israel" (as per the Hebrew) is in NIV, KJV, NKJV, NASB, LSB, CSB, HCSB, ASV, ERV, WEB, YLT, SLT, etc.
"angels of God" (as per the LXX) is in Brenton Septuagint
"Sons of God" (as per ???) is in ESV, BSB, MSB, ISV, MSB, NHEB, etc
"divine beings" (as per ???) is in NAB
"the gods" (as per ???) is in NRSV
"heavenly assembly" (as per ???) is in NET Bible.

The safest is to use faithful translations of the original Hebrew as listed above.

Foremost, let's make it clear that the two versions of Deuteronomy 32:8 are both legitimate. And that there is an ongoing debate which reading is the original one.
I don't know what the exact split is, but from my research, it seems that the majority sides with Septuagint and the Dead Sea Scrolls rather than the Masoretic Text.

According to the Masoretic version, the Most High divides the peoples
of the world specifically into the number of the sons of Israel,
ostensibly a reference to the 70 descendants of Jacob that came to
Egypt according to Deuteronomy 10:22 (as well as Genesis 46:27 and
Exodus 1:5 in MT, see case study 2). This is a strange claim: what is
so significant about this number? If anything, as noted above, the
symbolism goes in the opposite direction: the number of Jacob’s
descendants represents the peoples of the world.
In contrast, the reading in 4QDeutj and LXX makes perfect sense: The
Most High divided all the peoples of the world between the divine
beings, with each people possessing their own deity. Indeed, the next
verse continues this point nicely:
Deut 32:9 For YHWH’s portion is His people; Jacob, God’s own
allotment.
דברים לב:ט כִּי חֵלֶק יְ־הֹוָה עַמּוֹ יַעֲקֹב חֶבֶל נַחֲלָתוֹ.
This imagery of an assembly of divine beings, presided over by a
supreme god “(the Most High, ʿElyon)” appears also in Psalm 82 and 1
Kings 22:19, and is familiar from Ugaritic poetry. The MT’s “sons of
Israel” reflects a conscious intervention in the text by a scribe
uncomfortable with the polytheistic picture of divine beings, and
thus, that scribe de-mythologized the original polytheistic
description by replacing the word “god” with “Israel.”
https://www.thetorah.com/article/the-sons-of-israel-or-god-deuteronomy-32-8

As the article says, the number of Jacob’s descendants represents the peoples of the world, not the other way around. Israel was created with one purpose only, to be the rescue plan for the disenfranchised humanity. God disinherited humanity at Babel and created a new nation for Himself from Abraham and Sarah. The 70 nations of Genesis 10, all the descendants of Noah, were going to be reconciled to God through the family of Jacob, transformed into the kingdom of priests. That however did not go so well (the golden calf incident), and instead the nation of royal priests they became a nation with priests. After the call and the identity of Israel was reformed and recentred around the Messiah (the servant of Isaiah 49 is individual; Jesus as the new Israel was tested just like the people under Moses were, Matthew 2:13-4:11), He sends 70 (or 72 in some manuscripts) again:

1 And after these things, the LORD also appointed seventy others, and
sent them by twos before His face, to every city and place to where He
Himself was about to come, 2 then He said to them, “The harvest [is]
indeed abundant, but the workmen few; implore then the Lord of the
harvest, that He may put forth workmen to His harvest. ... 17 And the
seventy turned back with joy, saying, “Lord, and the demons are being
subjected to us in Your Name”; 18 and He said to them, “I was
beholding Satan having fallen as lightning from Heaven; 19 behold, I
give to you the authority to tread on serpents and scorpions, and on
all the power of the enemy, and nothing by any means will hurt you; 20
but do not rejoice in this, that the spirits are subjected to you, but
rejoice rather that your names were written in the heavens.” (Luke 10)

The 70 servants of the LORD had Jesus' authority over the dark powers, symbolically taking over from the angels of Deuteronomy 32:8.
Although Deuteronomy 32:8 does not specify what kind of spiritual being the 70 were, we can assume, they were still obedient to God back then after Babel. At some point, however, they became corrupted and led the nations astray, receiving their worship as false deities. As in Psalm 82.

And lest you lift up your eyes to the heavens, and have seen the sun,
and the moon, and the stars, all the host of the heavens, and have
been drawn away, and have bowed yourself to them and served them,
which your God YHWH has apportioned to all the peoples under all the
heavens. (Deuteronomy 4:19)
19 The earth is utterly broken, the earth is split apart, the earth is
violently shaken. 20 The earth staggers like a drunken man; it sways
like a hut; its transgression lies heavy upon it, and it falls, and
will not rise again.  21 On that day the Lord will punish the host
(powers/gods) of heaven, in heaven, and the kings of the earth, on the
earth. 22 They will be gathered together as prisoners in a pit; they
will be shut up in a prison, and after many days they will be
punished. 23 Then the moon will be confounded and the sun ashamed, for
the Lord of hosts reigns on Mount Zion and in Jerusalem, and his glory
will be before his elders. (Isaiah 24)
1 God presides in the great assembly; he renders judgment among the
“gods”: 2 “How long will you defend the unjust and show partiality to
the wicked? 3 Defend the weak and the fatherless; uphold the cause of
the poor and the oppressed. 4 Rescue the weak and the needy; deliver
them from the hand of the wicked. 5 “The ‘gods’ know nothing, they
understand nothing. They walk about in darkness; all the foundations
of the earth are shaken. 6 “I said, ‘You are “gods”; you are all sons
of the Most High.’ 7 But you will die like mere mortals; you will fall
like every other ruler.” 8 Rise up, O God, judge the earth, for all
the nations are your inheritance. (Psalm 82)

This is what the princes of Persia and Greece from the book of Daniel were. Rebellious angels that became false gods of the nations they were appointed to protect.
In the same fashion, we should interpret the departing of the glory of JHVH from the temple and then Jerusalem and the land in Ezekiel 10&11. Until the return of the glory, the people were under the protection of Michael, the prince of Israel.
Jesus is the embodiment of the glory of God, that returned to His temple at the appointed time to redeem and reclaim His people. The Messiah is the rescue plan for the nations. The Christ is the reversing of the Tower of Babel. So, do not fret, my friend. As a believer, you are a member of the Israel of God, regardless if you are a Jew or a gentile. And, you have the direct access to God through our saviour Jesus Christ.

Another translation of this passage runs along these lines:

When the Most High allotted each nation its heritage,
when he separated out human beings, He set up the boundaries of the peoples
after the number of the divine beings. But the Lord’s portion was his people;
his allotted share was Jacob. (NABRE)

This translation may be understood in a way that solves the problem that the OP raises for non-Israelites. The deity known as the "Most High" (elyon) apportioned each nation a heritage based on the number of divine beings (sons of god). The God of Israel (the text gives the name YHWH - יְהֹוָ֖ה - not actually "the Lord") was given the descendants of Jacob as his heritage. Other divine being were given other people as theirs.
Conclusion: This passage reflects the time when Israelites believed that other people were allowed to worship their own gods, but the people of Jacob were required to worship YHWH alone. Later prophets, however, thought that YHWH was the God of all people and that even gentiles would eventually worship him.
